# Firefox extension to make news item selectable in Facebook

Tags: gratis, facebook, firefox

When a friend posts a link on Facebook, a clickable item shows up.
Its text is not selectable.

Is there a Firefox extension to make the text selectable?
*For instance "Howling [...] slightly" in this screenshot:*

[image: Facebook can't select text of news]

Rationale: Sometimes I don't want to click, and just want to copy/paste a sentence of it into a search engine.

Free, ideally open source.

Replying to Timmy's comment: It is not an image, it is actually an image + 2 text zones, and the three are covered by a big link area:

```
<a href="http://www.clickhole.com/r/866fsd" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/www.clickhole.com\/r\/866fsd&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.referrer_log(this, &quot;http:\/\/www.clickhole.com\/r\/866fsd&quot;, &quot;\/si\/ajax\/l\/render_linkshim_log\/?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.clickhole.com\u00252Fr\u00252F866fsd&amp;h=mAQEX9pMK&amp;render_verification=0&amp;enc=AZPXu3tbPb2csSx-szTqUYkZiKB1UMFAkvlm2uXn00whmijm9y3DohQaauvdwE61WAM1Wa3hPys053ZJEtAZ6D07LLlxYvDO-3C3zQ-cq05eW5yNeANVw01arzv40yeCei_cp8eKAhOFs9o3SYw6GvcM&amp;d&quot;);"><div class="_6l- __c_"><div class="uiScaledImageContainer _6m5 fbStoryAttachmentImage" style="width:470px;height:246px;"><img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBYIcnL8MfJn-Mq&amp;w=470&amp;h=246&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fchimg.onionstatic.com%2F3307%2F16x9%2F1200.jpg&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale&amp;sx=0&amp;sy=15&amp;sw=1200&amp;sh=628" alt="" width="470" height="246"></div></div></a>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Facebook. If it inserts a preview of the linked webpage into the post, then it's most likely an image object and its text can't be selected as far as I know

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the text is there, and you are able to select (and copy) it, but not without firing the link? Or do they also prevent selecting the text? Would it be possible get a full working example (the code you posted shows only the link and the image)?

Comment: No, I am not able to select the text. Facebook often changes shape/HTML/CSS, but the point is that Facebook always makes link text unselectable, so I thought there would be a Firefox extension to deal with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an ad blocker or similar extension for this purpose, by defining an Element-Hiding rule which blocks the `<a>` element which is covering the content.

**In Chrome** I do this using AdBlock by right clicking onto the element and using the AdBlock context menu to "Block this ad". This opens a 'slider' interface for you to decide which level to block the element - in this case only the topmost anchor `<a>` tag.

**For Firefox** I have found two likely candidates - [RIP (Remove it Permanently)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remove-it-permanently/), or AdBlock Plus (open source) with the [Element Hiding Helper](https://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper) companion extension. These both seem to provide the functionality required to hide elements.

The generated rule will apply to all matching links, and persists across sessions. This leaves you with the desired selectable text, and if you still want to follow the link, the links Header text still remains a link.